# Pirates of Barracuda Bay 21322 — are there instructions to build it as a seaworthy ship directly?

Tags: sets, instructions

Are there official or unofficial instructions to build the ship directly, skipping the island stage? I figured that maybe, just maybe some fans prepared them.

The reason is that while it is great for adults as it is, to play with children it would make sense to use chronological order — play with ship, and then crash it.

Comment: So far [I don't see any sign of your request](https://rebrickable.com/sets/21322-1/pirates-of-barracuda-bay/?inventory=1#alt_builds).

Comment: I'm OK with this question staying unanswered, or with no as an answer if someone will be able to do reasonably wide search. I tried to look for it and didn't find, but I know I'm not the most experienced AFOL here ;)

Comment: That is fine, I will keep looking if I ever get time for it. It is quite clear to me that cutting out the island part of the instructions simply won't do it due to the design of the ship (it's basically an above-water shipwreck). I don't have the set, so if I don't find custom instructions I'm just gonna have to make them myself with Studio maybe. And my MOCs are generally not-so-good.

Comment: The above the water part seems not to be a problem, judging from the photos. It is all the little details that make it look old and beaten up you need to add all the way through the building process.

Comment: [I've found a studio file for the set but it is slightly incomplete and it is for display only](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=135556), which means that I probably can't help.

Answer (score 5):

LEGO provide instructions for the alternative build.

[image]

However these are given as an 'alteration' of the existing set rather than steps from scratch, this means you must create the official model first before making the changes.

[image]

The steps to convert the ship are on pages 412 to 450 of the instructions. Digital PDF instructions can be found on the [LEGO site](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/21322) but I have also uploaded an [image gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FXO3.jpg) of all the steps.

It is entirely possible to simply skip building the island stages as you will not need most of those parts in the conversion and the majority of the ship will be built.

My advice would be to follow the instructions ignoring those stages and simply assemble the three parts of the ship, making any alterations necessary using the instructions in the later half.